# magento2.3.4 installation page showing blank white color

Tags: magento2.3.4, php-7.3

i am trying to install magento 2.3.4 with php 7.3.16 but the installation page is showing blank white color.

[image]

Comment: only frontend blank showing ??

Comment: it is a installation setup page.